# If $a_1,a_2...$ is a set of natural numbers so that every number, except the first one, is the sum of the previous number and one of its' non-zero...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $a_1,a_2...$ is a set of natural numbers so that every number, except the first
> one, is the sum of the previous number and one of its' non-zero digits, prove that there's infinite even numbers in that set.

What I've thought about so far is that we assume the opposite, we only have odd numbers after a certain point. To keep getting odd numbers, we would have to have an even digit in the previous number, so that the next number is also odd. But, the last even digit in the number would eventually be turned into an odd digit after enough operations have passed. And due to the only difference between every two numbers in this set being a digit, an even one, all the other digits after it would be zero apart from the last digit being an odd digit (we added an even number so parity doesn't change).

My question is, am I on the right path or have I made a mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a solid idea to me. There is no reason to "assume the opposite", though. Just use the exact same argument to show that no matter how far out you go, there always has to be another even number after that.

Comment: I think you might do better to argue that (infinitely often) there will be a number in the sequence where all its digits are odd except perhaps the last; consider the parity of that number and the next in the sequence.

Comment: Sketch:  Look at numbers of the form $1^n01$.  The least number greater than that which has a non-zero even digit (not in the units place) is $1^n21 $ which is $20$ greater.  Thus there is no way to use your operation to "jump over" that block.